# When is disinformation the better term to use than misinformation?

Tags: word-usage, connotations

According to this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinformation),  disinformation is misinformation that is purposefully and intentionally disseminated. Does this term qualify for state media controlled by dictators like Hugo Chavez or Muhammad Gaddafi?

Is disinformation the correct term to describe the manufacturing of fake news and the distribution of it through media channels? Is misinformation the outcome of it?

I hope my question makes sense. I am trying to educate myself on the topic.

Comment: I think that really its kind of arbitrary semantic differences that will vary depending on who you ask.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that it doesn't apply to state media? The article seems pretty straightforward. I could write an answer that just re-iterates the article, but that doesn't seem very useful. Just wondering if there is something more to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> misinformation

is more *accidental* on the part of the receiver of information.

One way to remember this is the *mis-* prefix

> *mis*heard - heard incorrectly
>   *mis*take - to make an error
>   *mis*understand - to understand incorrectly

On the other hand

> disinformation

is *intentional* on the part of whomever is putting out information, it is a form of propaganda and more recently has been called *Fake News*.

> Disinformation will cause misinformation among people.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Accepted. I cannot vote you up though. I don't have enough reputation points. Sorry.

Comment: Glad my answer helped. You'll have more reputation soon enough!